# Not possible to connect 2 stations -- Sid Meier's RailRoads

Tags: sid-meiers-railroads

I Want to connect 2 stations in SidMeier's Railroad

Bur when I buy a train to connect it, the City (Blythe) appears in black, and doesn't allow me to  connect it with the Blythe Annex.

The city is connected to the annex, but I don't know why don't allow me.

Thanks in advance!

**Blythe**
[image]
**Blythe Annex**
[image]
**Train route Selection**
[image]

Comment: I realised that from some reason the railroads seams to be conected, but they aren in some part.. :S

  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have come across something similar, it happens at times that when connecting two pieces of track together they don't actually "join" and therefore there isn't a route to get between the two stations.

The obvious solution is to delete and re-create that section of track (or drawing an additional track from the existing rail to another platform at both ends and then removing the existing route on tracks that have trains running on them already).

Answer (score 0):

The rails are overlapping but not connected. This is indicated by the white squares near the ends of the tracks - they indicate track ends, as can be clearly seen in the second picture. This often happens with bridges, you can't connect a track to a bridge, only the other way around. When this happens, just delete the conflicting track and build it again, but properly.